# 12.10 does not boot sometimes from the hard drive, but it does consistently from the CD

Tags: boot, 12.10, login

I have recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.10. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I cleared everything from my computer, but it randomly stops at different screens.

1. Only a purple screen comes up.
2. I can choose Ubuntu from a list and a blinking white dot appears in the top left corner.
3. The previous things happen and the Ubuntu login screen appears an I can log in.

It is random. and I have not changed anything. I can always insert the bootable CD and it will work every time.

Answer (score 1):

If the same thing happens again, run `dmesg` command (in console/terminal, you may want to | less to better look at the output) and try to figure out what is failing.

You can also comment out the following line in /etc/default/grub

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

This will help you to see the output during the boot process.

Comment: Don't forget sudo update-grub after the edit. @Terry: Please could you provide a bit more details on how to check dmesg and edit your answer as needed.

Comment: dmsg is a command that we can use in terminals.

Answer (score 0):

http://dan-orth.com/wp/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-asus-u46e-resolving-boot-issue/

I followed the instructions on this site and that seems to have fixed the issue. It just started 3 times in a row. I will let you know if it starts acting up again.

Scott

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Basically you open the terminal and type or copy and paste: gksu gedit /etc/default/grub  Then you go down to the line in the file that opens that says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=.  A value of ”quiet splash”  After where it says quiet splash but before the quotation mark ends you type noapic. So the line then becomes GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=.  A value of ”quiet splash noapic” Then you save the file and type sudo update-grub to update the file then everything is fixed. I have booted successfully into Ubuntu every time since I have done this. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem: dual boot win7 and Ubuntu 12.10 fresh install both 64 bit.

Only the `noapic` thingy seems to have helped the problem. But using that the fan keeps spinning really fast and loudly even when the pc is idle. Is there any other way to work out this problem without using `noapic` ? Maybe `nolapic` or one of these variations so that heat management and power consumption is not being affected??